# Obtaining the location of the redirected uri

Tags: java, url, uri

This is what my URL look like:

> https://localhost.com.ua/oauth/authorize?client_id=SS&response_type=code&scope=N_FULL&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost/

Upon posting that in java (http post request), it'll be re-directed to this URI:

> https://kuma.ruto/v1/0auth/grant?state=some&code=**YrnYdnHdY**

How can I obtain the re-directed URI and get the code value?

Below is the code snippet:

> String data = "email=p@f.com&password=Airtel@2017";
>                                            URL url = new URL("https://login.something.com/v1/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&state=none&email=p@f.com&client_id=jkhsdhaskfhdash&password=Airtel@2017&redirect_uri=https://login.something.com&code=none");
>
> ```
>                                      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>
>                                      con.setDoOutput(true);
>                                      OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
>                                                                      con.getOutputStream());
>                                      writer.write(data);
>                                      InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
>                                      System.out.println( "redirected url: " + con.getURL() );
>
>
>                                      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>                                                                      (conn.getInputStream())));
>                                      System.out.println( "redirected url2: " + con.getURL() );
>
>                                      String st = null;
>                                      String output;
>                                      System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
>                                      while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
>                                                      System.out.println(output);
>
>                                                      st += output;
>                                      }
>                                      Spdfast111 test = new Spdfast111();
>                                      Map<String, String> map=test.getFormParams(st);
>                                      URL url1 = new URL("https://login.something.com/v1/oauth/grant?value_one="+map.get("value_one")+"&value_two="+map.get("value_two")+"redirected_uri=https://login.something.com/v1/oauth/token");
>                                      System.out.println("==========================="+url1);
>                                      HttpURLConnection con1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
>
>                                      System.out.println( "orignal url: " + con1.getURL() );
>                                      con1.connect();
>                                      System.out.println( "connected url: " + con1.getURL() );
>                                      InputStream is1 = connn.getInputStream();
>                                      System.out.println( "redirected url: " + con1.getURL() );
>                                      is1.close();
> ```

Comment: Please include code about how you do the POST request.
You can read the URL from the response.

Comment: I just included the code. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following example:

https://github.com/mconf/bbb-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mconf/bbb/api/JoinServiceBase.java#L151

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(joinUrl);
        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(method, context);
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            log.debug("HTTP GET {} return {}", joinUrl, httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        HttpUriRequest currentReq = (HttpUriRequest) context.getAttribute( 
                ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);

        if (!currentReq.getURI().getPath().equals("/client/BigBlueButton.html")) {
            log.warn("It was redirected to {} instead of /client/BigBlueButton.html: the server was branded" +
                    " and the HTML name was changed, or it's an error. However, it will continue processing", currentReq.getURI().getPath());
        }

        HttpHost currentHost = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute( 
                ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
        String enterUrl = currentHost.toURI() + "/bigbluebutton/api/enter";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this example?:

```
    // loop until no more redirections are 
    for (;;) {
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            return null;
        }
        if(proxy != null) {
            ucn = downloadURL.openConnection(proxy);
        } else {
            ucn = downloadURL.openConnection();
        }
        HttpURLConnection hucn = doConfigureURLConnection(ucn);

        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            return null;

        ucn.connect();

        int rc = hucn.getResponseCode();
        boolean isRedirect = 
                rc == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP ||
                rc == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM;
        if (!isRedirect) {
            break;
        }

        String addr = hucn.getHeaderField(HTTP_REDIRECT_LOCATION);
        URL newURL = new URL(addr);
        if (!downloadURL.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase(newURL.getProtocol())) {
            throw new ResourceRedirectException(newURL);
        }
        downloadURL = newURL;
    }
```

Full code here: http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=eLvMdX5b01HDEtWkU2TEPg13uu0&cid=xJ52R73llJU&s=Obtaining%20the%20location%20of%20the%20redirected%20uri&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&filterChecked=true&fp=1141&mp,=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0